# Can one convert a String to an enum value?

Tags: java, enums, bufferedreader

I have got code like this:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\file.txt"));
String text = in.readLine();//lets say text is now "asd"
```

Now after that i have got a method:

```
private static void doSomething(Enum word){
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to somehow convert this text into an Enum?

Comment: That's a strange method `doSomething`, which requires its argzment to be *any* `Enum`, instead of one specific `enum` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use [`Enum.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
WhateverEnum.valueOf(someString);
```

Comment: yeah but i would have to make at the beggining of the class private static enum WhateverEnum and add there asd, so i would need to know in the first place that asd is in the file, what if i dont? Am i correct?

Comment: @user1451415 - You're going to need to know the type of the enum that you're parsing the value into anyway. There's no way you can randomly parse a string into the correct Enum value without knowing the type of Enum you're parsing into.

Comment: Ok so i will just need to make new enum at the beggining with words that are in the text file and later it will be easy, thx for help :)

Comment: If you are enumerating the words in a text file, why not leave it as a String rather than convert it to an `enum`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either

```
 MyEnum me = Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, word);
```

or

```
 MyEnum me = MyEnum.valueof(word)
```

Comment: yeah but i would have to make at the beggining of the class private static enum WhateverEnum and add there asd, so i would need to know in the first place that asd is in the file, what if i dont? Am i correct?

Comment: You need to know which enum you want to convert the string to.  If you want a generic "enum" you can leave it as a String.